# Is there really a limited supply of bitcoin?

Tags: money-supply

I don't get how there's a limited supply of 21 million bitcoin if we can go into the infinite amount of decimal places.

So for example, you can't go less then 1 cent if we take USD. in BTC, you can have 0.00000001 or however many zeros after the point, not sure but I would assume it's alot. So isn't there alot more than 21 million bitcoins, if we take in decimals into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't go into an "infinite" amount of decimal places. The smallest unit of Bitcoin is the *satoshi*, which is 0.00000001 bitcoin.

There will be a total of 2100000000000000 satoshi.

Answer (score 0):

Fractions or decimals of the whole don't make more of the whole.  21x10^6 is a finite number but it can be divided infinitely. Division doesn't increase the finite number, it just increases the number of "pieces" of the original number. Think of $1. You can produce four quarters from $1 which is more pieces but still only a total of $1.